# Android simple way to record sound and stream that to a server?

Tags: android

Is there a simple way to record sound and stream it to a server in real time?

Thanks, 
Leslie

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no direct API that would do that..

What people usually do is read the media file as it is being saved, and upload it progressively to server.

See how some open-source projects do it:

http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/

http://code.google.com/p/ipcamera-for-android/

http://code.google.com/p/camdroiduni/